# 2-Dimensional Array to Hold the Sales Totals for Used and New Cars

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I had to create a java program for my class for a car dealership that sells both new and used cars.  We need a program that can ask the user for the number of sales people.  Add their names to a String array.  Next, ask for sales totals for new cars and used cars separately. Here is my program so far. I was wondering if there was a way to include the following three headers for my table: Name, Used Sales, and New Sales.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numemployees;
    System.out.println("Enter the Number of Employees: ");
    numemployees = in.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[numemployees];
    String line;

  for (int i = 0; i < numemployees; i++)
  {
      System.out.print("Enter the name of the Salesperson: ");
      names[i] = in.next();
  }

  double [][] sales = new double [numemployees][2];
  for(int j = 0; j < numemployees; j++)
  {
      System.out.println("Enter New Car Sales: "+ names[j]);
      sales[j][0] = in.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter Used Car Sales: ");
      sales[j][1] = in.nextDouble();

  }

  for(int x = 0; x < numemployees; x++)
  {
       System.out.println(names[x] + "\t" + sales[x][0] + "\t" + sales[x][0] + "\t");
  }


  }
}
```

Comment: just use System.out.println("Name"+"\t"+"Used Sales"+"\t"+"New Sales."); before  for(int x = 0; x < numemployees; x++)

Answer (score 1):

To print header use System.out.println:

```
System.out.println("Name \t Used Sales \t New Sales");
for(int x = 0; x < numemployees; x++)
{
      System.out.println(names[x] + "\t" + sales[x][0] + "\t" + sales[x][1] + "\t");
}
```

And one more think be careful with indexes: You have used `System.out.println(names[x] + "\t" + sales[x][0] + "\t" + sales[x][0] + "\t");`. The problem is with `sales[x][0]` It will only twice print same value.

Comment: Code only questions are looked down on.  Please give some explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1I would suggest using String.format for this. Then you get some nice formatting along with it.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s%-10s%-10s", "Name", "Used Sales", "New Sales"));
for(int x = 0; x < numemployees; x++)
{
    System.out.println(String.format("%8.2f%8.2f%8.2f", names[x], sales[x][0], sales[x][1]));
}
```